# Batch robocopy pdf files created today

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

i want to copy pdf files created today incl. their path to a
destination folder. I tried robocopy but even i use /S as parameter
folders without any content getting copied.
Here is my script:

```
robocopy "h:\origin\" "G:\destination" *.pdf /B /S /mt:4 /eta /XA:H  /XD "H:\origin\tmp" /l /LOG:sync.log
```

thanks for your help

Comment: sorry posted wrong version of the script: robocopy "h:\origin\" "G:\destination" *.pdf /B /S /mt:4 /eta /XA:H  /maxage:1 /XD "H:\origin\tmp" /l /LOG:sync.log

Comment: Edit your question.  Do not put your code in a comment.